# Change display CSS on hover on another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my HTML code.

```
<img src="images/maxicon.png" class="iconimg" width="100%" alt="">
<a href="#"><img src="images/link.png" class="linkimg" alt=""></a>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.linkimg {
    display: none;
}

.iconimg:hover  .linkimg {
    display: block;
}
```

I have tried several solutions available on stackoverflow, but it just wouldn't work. I tried the ~ and + approach as well. I am not sure why it doesn't work.
What I want to do is, when I hover over .iconimg, I want .linkimg to show up. Initially .linkimg is hidden.

Comment: .iconimg is not a parent of .linkimg so the style won't apply

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sprite css` if you use `<img>` tags then sometimes hover image may takes time to load. For that moment user get blank. In `sprite css` you just need to change `background-position` only.

Comment: Visit https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/. You need to change position in `:hover`

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
.iconimg {
    display: block;
}
.iconimg:hover + a {
    display: block;
}
a {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is a working demo https://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/Lqa1x753/

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not target the correct element because .iconimg:hover .linkimg implies the .linkimg inside an element with the class .iconimg

However, your .linkimg is a child of the sibling a tag of .iconimg in the DOM. So you have to use a sibling combinator to select the .linkimg inside the a tag.

```
.iconimg:hover ~ a .linkimg {
    display: block;
}
```

```css
.linkimg {
    display: none;
}

.iconimg:hover ~ a .linkimg {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" class="iconimg" width="100%" alt="">
<a href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" class="linkimg" alt=""></a>
```

A better way to accomplish the same effect would be placing .linkimg at the a tag.

```css
.linkimg {
    display: none;
}

.iconimg:hover ~ .linkimg { /* .iconimg:hover ~ a.linkimg is also acceptable */
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" class="iconimg" width="100%" alt="">
<a class="linkimg" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" alt=""></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
.linkimg {
    visibility:hidden;
}

.iconimg:hover + a .linkimg {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2q9d080u/1/)